# Control Windows app (HMA VPN) using PyWinAuto

Tags: python, windows-10, pywinauto

I am trying to write Python code to request my vpn software to connect / disconnect upon certain conditions. I use HMA VPN and am running on Windows 10. Python 3.9.5.

The PyWinAuto module would appear to have the required functionality, but I cannot get it to work correctly. I'm sure it's my coding, not the module itself... ;)

I'm fairly sure I'm referring to the control incorrectly when I call it with the click() method, but can anyone suggest the correct approach, given the dump_tree that I have included? (I have tried tens of variations based based on the code snippets in the [Getting Started guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html), but no joy).

I'm looking to be able to toggle Button4 in GroupBox2, which is named either "Connect" or "Disconnect", depending on the current state of the VPN. I also want to be able to click Button5, "Change IP Address", but once I figure out one button, the other should be easy.

Any thoughts where I am going wrong?

My code snippet is as follows:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application

Desktop(backend='uia').HMAVPN.dump_tree()
app = Application().start('C:\Program Files\Privax\HMA VPN\Vpn.exe', timeout=5)
dlg_spec = app.window(title='HMA VPN')
dlg_spec.AvastChromiumWindow.Pane2.Document.GroupBox2.Button4.click()
```

The resulting output is as follows:

```
Control Identifiers:

Dialog - 'HMA VPN'    (L-149, T68, R551, B638)
['HMA VPNDialog', 'HMA VPN', 'Dialog']
child_window(title="HMA VPN", control_type="Window")
   | 
   | Pane - 'AvastChromiumWindow'    (L-149, T68, R551, B638)
   | ['Pane', 'AvastChromiumWindowPane', 'AvastChromiumWindow', 'Pane0', 'Pane1']
   | child_window(title="AvastChromiumWindow", control_type="Pane")
   |    | 
   |    | Pane - ''    (L-149, T68, R551, B638)
   |    | ['Pane2', '\ue01bPane', '\ue01bPane0', '\ue01bPane1']
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Document - '            Original IP   91.90.253.244 New IP   80.255.5.198    Original IP   91.90.253.244     Location Germany, Berlin              '    (L-149, T68, R551, B638)
   |    |    | ['\ue01b    \ue014  \ue007      Original IP \xa0 91.90.253.244 New IP \xa0 80.255.5.198 \ue019   Original IP \xa0 91.90.253.244   \xa0 Location Germany, Berlin \ue005             Document', 'Document', '\ue01b    \ue014  \ue007      Original IP \xa0 91.90.253.244 New IP \xa0 80.255.5.198 \ue019   Original IP \xa0 91.90.253.244   \xa0 Location Germany, Berlin \ue005             ']
   |    |    | child_window(title="            Original IP   91.90.253.244 New IP   80.255.5.198    Original IP   91.90.253.244     Location Germany, Berlin              ", auto_id="7211296", control_type="Document")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | GroupBox - ''    (L-149, T68, R551, B104)
   |    |    |    | ['\ue01bGroupBox', 'GroupBox', '\ue01bGroupBox0', '\ue01bGroupBox1', 'GroupBox0', 'GroupBox1']
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Button - 'Preferences'    (L-134, T76, R-114, B96)
   |    |    |    |    | ['PreferencesButton', 'Preferences', 'Button', 'Button0', 'Button1']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Preferences", auto_id="hma_title__preferences", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    | Static - ''    (L-134, T76, R-114, B96)
   |    |    |    |    |    | ['Static', '\ue01b', '\ue01bStatic', 'Static0', 'Static1']
   |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Button - 'Minimize'    (L486, T76, R506, B96)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Minimize', 'Button2', 'MinimizeButton']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Minimize", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    | Static - ''    (L486, T76, R506, B96)
   |    |    |    |    |    | ['\ue014Static', 'Static2', '\ue014']
   |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Button - 'Close'    (L516, T76, R536, B96)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Close', 'Button3', 'CloseButton']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Close", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    | Static - ''    (L516, T76, R536, B96)
   |    |    |    |    |    | ['Static3', '\ue007', '\ue007Static']
   |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | GroupBox - ''    (L-149, T68, R551, B638)
   |    |    |    | ['\ue01bGroupBox2', 'GroupBox2']
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L111, T120, R291, B300)
   |    |    |    |    | ['\ue01bImage', 'Image']
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Button - 'Disconnect'    (L126, T323, R276, B383)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Button4', 'DisconnectButton', 'Disconnect']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Disconnect", auto_id="dashboard_switch", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Original IP'    (L68, T414, R135, B430)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Original IPStatic', 'Static4', 'Original IP', 'Original IPStatic0', 'Original IPStatic1', 'Original IP0', 'Original IP1']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Original IP", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Static - ' '    (L164, T412, R168, B427)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Static5', '\xa0Static', '\xa0', '\xa0Static0', '\xa0Static1', '\xa00', '\xa01']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title=" ", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Static - '91.90.253.244'    (L184, T414, R266, B429)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Static6', '91.90.253.244Static', '91.90.253.244', '91.90.253.244Static0', '91.90.253.244Static1', '91.90.253.2440', '91.90.253.2441']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="91.90.253.244", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Static - 'New IP'    (L68, T442, R113, B458)
   |    |    |    |    | ['New IP', 'Static7', 'New IPStatic']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="New IP", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Static - ' '    (L164, T440, R168, B455)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Static8', '\xa0Static2', '\xa02']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title=" ", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Static - '80.255.5.198'    (L184, T442, R258, B457)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Static9', '80.255.5.198', '80.255.5.198Static']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="80.255.5.198", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Button - 'Change IP Address'    (L294, T416, R334, B456)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Change IP AddressButton', 'Button5', 'Change IP Address']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Change IP Address", auto_id="ip_change", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Original IP'    (L95, T428, R162, B444)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Original IPStatic2', 'Static10', 'Original IP2']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Original IP", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Static - ' '    (L191, T426, R196, B441)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Static11', '\xa0Static3', '\xa03']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title=" ", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Static - '91.90.253.244'    (L211, T428, R293, B443)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Static12', '91.90.253.244Static2', '91.90.253.2442']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="91.90.253.244", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Button - 'Location Germany, Berlin'    (L31, T489, R371, B569)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Button6', 'Location Germany, BerlinButton', 'Location Germany, Berlin']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Location Germany, Berlin", auto_id="dashboard_chooseLocation", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    | Static - ' '    (L51, T507, R55, B522)
   |    |    |    |    |    | ['Static13', '\xa0Static4', '\xa04']
   |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title=" ", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Location'    (L111, T511, R164, B526)
   |    |    |    |    |    | ['Static14', 'Location', 'LocationStatic']
   |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Location", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Germany, Berlin'    (L111, T529, R219, B546)
   |    |    |    |    |    | ['Static15', 'Germany, Berlin', 'Germany, BerlinStatic']
   |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Germany, Berlin", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    | Static - ''    (L331, T519, R351, B539)
   |    |    |    |    |    | ['Static16', '\ue005', '\ue005Static']
   |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Button - 'More'    (L420, T107, R528, B137)
   |    |    |    |    | ['More', 'Button7', 'MoreButton']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="More", control_type="Button")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Pane - ''    (L-149, T68, R551, B638)
   |    |    | ['Pane3', '\ue01bPane2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\db533\VirtualBox VMs\pycharm-gunabot\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 250, in __resolve_control
    ctrl = wait_until_passes(
  File "C:\Users\db533\VirtualBox VMs\pycharm-gunabot\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\db533\PycharmProjects\GunaBot\hma_control.py", line 19, in <module>
    dlg_spec.AvastChromiumWindow.Pane2.Document.GroupBox2.Button4.click()
  File "C:\Users\db533\VirtualBox VMs\pycharm-gunabot\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 379, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Users\db533\VirtualBox VMs\pycharm-gunabot\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 261, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Users\db533\VirtualBox VMs\pycharm-gunabot\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\db533\VirtualBox VMs\pycharm-gunabot\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 203, in __get_ctrl
    dialog = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**criteria[0]))
  File "C:\Users\db533\VirtualBox VMs\pycharm-gunabot\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'HMA VPN', 'backend': 'win32', 'process': 40580}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cracked it! The following code let's me toggle the Connect / Disconnect button and change the IP.

```
from pywinauto import Desktop,Application
vpn_app = Application(backend="uia").start('C:\Program Files\Privax\HMA VPN\Vpn.exe')
dialog=Desktop(backend="uia").HMA
panel0=dialog.Pane
# Command to connect / disconnect the VPN: connect_button.click()
connect_button=panel0.ConnectButton
# Command to change the IP address: changeIP.click()
changeIP=panel0.Button5
# Check VPN state:
# 0 if disconnected
# 1 if connected
print(connect_button.get_toggle_state())

# Command to connect / disconnect the VPN: connect_button.click()
connect_button=panel0.ConnectButton
connect_button.click()

# Command to change the IP address: changeIP.click()
changeIP=panel0.Button5
changeIP.click()

# Check VPN state:
# 0 if disconnected
# 1 if connected
print(connect_button.get_toggle_state())
```